# Timing sending and receiving the same packet

Tags: c++, c, unix, boost

I would like to time how quickly the latency is of a system by sending a packet with the same dest IP as the source IP. Is this relatively simple to do?

How would you custom-build the packets?

Would setting the two IP addresses achieve what I am after?

What is the best timing method?

Any tips/ideas at a low/high level would be greatly appreciated. I intend to use C/C++ on Unix with the boost libraries and libpcap.

EDIT: I should add I will be doing this on a home network, behind a router. I presume the packet will go to the router and come straight back if I were to use 192.168.2.1 (local IP of my system) for the source and dest addresses.

Comment: It probably won't hit the router at all. The network driver may notice they are the same and copy out to in therefore not even reaching the network physically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just try ping to your own IP. this will produce ICMP packets. There are libraries which also allows you to do the same from an application.

If you want to create packets for yourself you can use socket API. Remember, you can send the source IP address and destination IP address as same, but the port number needs to be different.

For timing you need can use `gettimeofday` function.

EDIT: 
you *can* ping from your C++ program. See: http://verplant.org/liboping/ or check out some other forum. The reason i emphasized on ping is because it returns right back from the network stack. If you send a UDP packet on the other hand, expecting the application to return and echo, then the processing time of the packet on the listening server gets added.

If you ping to local machine ip (or even `lo`) it returns *without* going to switch or next hop router. It will respond even if you remove your eth cable or wifi.

What you are trying to do is implemented in NTP daemon with NTP protocol though.

Comment: So I "ping" from my C++ program? The ICMP packets will remain on the network stack or go to the router and back?

Comment: Appended my answer to your query.

Comment: Thanks Dipan. Out of curiousity would you know the answer to my last comment above to Joachim?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom package for this. Just create a socket connecting to the same ip-address as the server, and start sending packages. Note that these packages will never leave the network stack, so what you will be measuring is basically how quick the system copies data between user-space and kernel-space.

For the timing, you can use the [`clock`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock) function, it's probably the one most widely used for such things.

Comment: Hi Joachim, are you saying the only thing which I wont be measuring is the actual physical delivery of packets across a medium? If so, that is not a big problem.

Comment: Just one last question: the reason I am asking this is because I want to learn more regarding high frequency trading. From the point of view of finding extra speed, is the linux network stack already heavilly optimised. In other words, do you think this is one of the parts of linux HF developers re-write? Or, like TCP, is this something which has developed to be as efficient as possible?

Comment: I wouldn't be the authority to say this, but from any application stand point, i would believe the network stack of Linux to be most efficient. Much of the performance and often more importantly scalability will come by efficiently handling responses at application layer (design easiest to process messages) and by creating more resources(servers) with efficient routing.

Comment: Thanks Dipan, thats good because Im not too sure if I could get stuck into re-writing Linux yet!